# getting error on raspbian boot up failing to start Load Kernel Modules

Tags: raspbian, kernel

Getting error on Raspbian boot up:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service -l
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-09-01 06:45:01 UTC; 3h 17min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 128 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 128 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 01 06:45:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Sep 01 06:45:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 01 06:45:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
```

Contents of modules.conf

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6                    File: /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf                                              

# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

i2c-dev
```

there is no `/etc/modules.load.d/cups` and I have disabled `cups` and `cups-browsed` services using `sudo rcconf` and printer is also unplugged 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more details from the files "/etc/modules.load.d/modules.conf" and "ls /etc/modules.load.d/cups*". Usually this happens when the hardware is missing and kernel tries to load the module on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug already Ubuntu (Debian) is looking at from the 16.04 release.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574163[image]

This might be fixed in some patch soon i guess. Hope this is not causing any other problems for your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Good to hear that I am really feeling that I testing pi to the core

Comment: There's not really a bug there by my reading of that (a lot of bug reports don't in the end equal bugs), except to the extent that someone may have triggered *expected* behavior due what *may* be a sort of bug when upgrading from ubuntu 14 to 16.  Anyway, the root cause of the issue in all the cases reported there are modules that aren't being loaded because they are non-existent.  You should try what is suggested, `sudo SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug /lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load` and if the output doesn't explain it for you, paste it into the question.